# Address unequal variance between groups before applying contrasts for a linear model? (r)

Tags: r, regression, robustness

**My Goal:** I have an ordinal factor variable (5 levels) to which I would like to apply contrasts to test for a linear trend. However, the factor groups have heterogeneity of variance.

**What I've done:** Upon recommendation, I used `lmRob()` from `robust` pckg to create a robust linear model, then applied the contrasts.

```
# assign the codes for a linear contrast of 5 groups, save as object
contrast5 <- contr.poly(5)

# set contrast property of sf1 to contain the weights
contrasts(SCI$sf1) <- contrast5

# fit and save a robust model (exhaustive instead of subsampling)
robmod.sf1 <- lmRob(ICECAP_A ~ sf1, data = SCI, nrep = Exhaustive)

summary.lmRob(robmod.sf1)
```

**My problem:** I have since been reading that robust regression is more suited to address outliers, and not heterogeneity of variance. (bottom of https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/robust-regression/_ ) This UCLA page (among others) suggests the `sandwich` package to get heteroskedastic-consistent (HC) standard errors (such as in https://thestatsgeek.com/2014/02/14/the-robust-sandwich-variance-estimator-for-linear-regression-using-r/ ).

But these examples use a series of functions/calls to generate output that gives you the HC that could be used to calculate confidence intervals, t-values, p-values etc.

My thinking is that if I use `vcovHC()`, I could get the HC std errors, but the HC std errors would not have been 'applied'/a property of the model, so I couldn't pass the model (with the HC errors) through a function to apply the contrasts that I ultimately want. I hope I am not conflating two separate concepts, but surely if a function addresses/down-weights outliers, that should at least somewhat address unequal variances as well?

Can anyone confirm if my reasoning is sound (and thus remain with `lmRob()`? Or suggest how I could just correct my standard errors **and still apply the contrasts**?

Comment: does log-transforming your response variable help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vcovHC` is the right function to deal with heteroscedasticity. HC stands for heteroscedasticity-consistent estimator. This will *not* downweight outliers in estimates of model effects, but it will calculated the CIs and p-values differently to accommodate the impact of such outlying observations. `lmRob` *does* downweight outlying values and does not handle heteroscedasticity

See more here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50778/sandwich-estimator-intuition/50788#50788

Comment: Thank you, AdamO! I cross-posted my question (I'm new and unsure of the remits of overflow vs exchange)... I have a new concern about drastically (and unexpectedly) different p-values and a question about reporting means /std devs after using `vcovHC`. Would you be able to help me out over here? Updated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450776/address-unequal-variance-between-groups-before-applying-contrasts-for-a-linear-m